# Unity Google Play leaderboard error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I'm making 2D mobile game by unity. using gpgs plugin, successed in google play login, but Social.showReaderboardUI doesn't work.
I searched for same solution, but I can't find what was wrong.. please help me!
logcat:

```
09-02 20:00:52.288 1290-1290/? D/ViewRootImpl@f60ae3d[UnityPlayerActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
09-02 20:00:52.468 1290-1290/? D/ViewRootImpl@f60ae3d[UnityPlayerActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
09-02 20:00:52.472 1290-1340/? I/Unity: Starting Auth with token client.

    (Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/DebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 51)
09-02 20:00:52.487 1290-1340/? W/Unity: *** [Play Games Plugin DLL] 09/02/18 11:00:52 +00:00 ERROR: Exception launching token request: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.games.bridge.TokenFragment

    (Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/DebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 51)
09-02 20:00:52.488 1290-1340/? W/Unity: *** [Play Games Plugin DLL] 09/02/18 11:00:52 +00:00 ERROR: UnityEngine.AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.games.bridge.TokenFragment
      at UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.CheckException () [0x00091] in <874146cf7d2d43c890e7556e286193df>:0 
      at UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.CallStaticObjectMethod (System.IntPtr clazz, System.IntPtr methodID, UnityEngine.jvalue[] args) [0x00011] in <874146cf7d2d43c890e7556e286193df>:0 
      at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject._CallStatic[ReturnType] (System.String methodName, System.Object[] args) [0x002d6] in <874146cf7d2d43c890e7556e286193df>:0 
      at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject.CallStatic[ReturnType] (System.String methodName, System.Object[] args) [0x00001] in <874146cf7d2d43c890e7556e286193df>:0 
      at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject.FindClass (System.String name) [0x0001d] in <874146cf7d2d43c890e7556e286193df>:0 
      at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaClass._AndroidJavaClass (System.String className) [0x00012] in <874146cf7d2d43c890e7556e286193df>:0 
      at UnityEngi
09-02 20:01:27.450 1290-1290/? D/ViewRootImpl@f60ae3d[UnityPlayerActivity]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: frame=Rect(0, 0 - 800, 1280) ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 32 - 0, 0) or=1
09-02 20:01:27.480 1428-13816/? D/WindowManager: finishDrawingWindow: Window{8595e9fd0 u0 com.HAE.Fillette/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity} mDrawState=DRAW_PENDING
09-02 20:01:27.520 1290-1290/? D/ViewRootImpl@f60ae3d[UnityPlayerActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0
09-02 20:01:27.559 1290-1290/? D/ViewRootImpl@f60ae3d[UnityPlayerActivity]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][800,1280] newFrame=[0,0][800,1280] result=0x3 surface={isValid=true -1693452288} surfaceGenerationChanged=false
09-02 20:01:27.560 1428-13815/? D/WindowManager: finishDrawingWindow: Window{8595e9fd0 u0 com.HAE.Fillette/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity} mDrawState=HAS_DRAWN
09-02 20:01:28.558 1290-1290/? D/ViewRootImpl@f60ae3d[UnityPlayerActivity]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][800,1280] newFrame=[0,0][800,1280] result=0x3 surface={isValid=true -1693452288} surfaceGenerationChanged=false
09-02 20:01:28.559 1428-10491/? D/WindowManager: finishDrawingWindow: Window{8595e9fd0 u0 com.HAE.Fillette/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity} mDrawState=HAS_DRAWN
```

Unity version : 2017.3.0f3
JDK : 1.8.0
GPGS Plugin version: 0.9.50
Asset/Plugin/Android
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGyVA.png)